# Can I just phone an editor if he never answered back via email?

Tags: publications, etiquette, editors

Last year, I submitted a book manuscript to Springer. The academic editor told me that it looked great and that he would send it for peer review and would contact me in due course. Both the publisher editor and a production person were also involved. I even sent the index for the book. But I haven’t heard of the project for 10 months now. Not a pip. I don’t even know if it’s under peer review, since it’s not an article and therefore I don’t have the journal’s progress bar to check on. I sent emails to both the academic and the publisher editors on the 7-month mark and one per month since then asking about status. I have never received an answer from anyone since March of 2023. I found phone numbers for the academic editor at his university. Is it OK if I phone him out of the blue? I have never before phoned a person I don't personally know to inquire on academic matters, but I'd really like an answer. What do you all advice? Since I signed a contract, should I just assume that they didn't like the manuscript and tell them that if they won't answer in a reasonable period I will explore other publishers? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try phoning the person who works at Springer first. They will not mind being phoned. If there is no phone number on their emails, phone the office and ask for them. If the receptionist tells you to send an email, tell them you have already done that several times.

If that doesn't work, phone the academic editor.

When you phone, be very gentle and polite and say you would just like to know the status of the publication.

Note that peer review can sometimes take a long time and a book takes longer to review than an article. But I think it was reasonable to contact them after 7 months.

Comment: Why the Springer editor first? Last time I heard the ball was with the academic editor instead…

Comment: The Springer editor works in a business and is less likely to be irritated by a phone call out of the blue, which is what you seem to be concerned about. (Of course it is not actually out of the blue as you have emailed them several times. )

Comment: I will, thanks. The problem is that if a book takes a year to be reviewed, then by the time they finish reviewing it the author could already need to update the book! Which is my case. And it could lead to an infinite loop!!

Comment: Yes, academic publishing can be very slow. If you are able to talk to the Springer person, you could gently ask them about this too - will it be possible to make some updates, or is it too late for that? They might say that for minor things that is fine but for major things it is too late. It won't lead to an infinite loop.